# How to add a comparison counter for merge sort in python?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, merge, comparison

The code that I'm using is below.

I want to add a comparison counter to this code but the one that I have now will display the same number as the number of elements.

```
def MergeSort(argShuffledList):
    intNumOfComp = 0
    if len(argShuffledList)>1:
        intMidValue = len(argShuffledList)//2
        listLeftHalf = argShuffledList[:intMidValue]
        listRightHalf = argShuffledList[intMidValue:]

        MergeSort(listLeftHalf)
        MergeSort(listRightHalf)

        i=0
        j=0
        k=0
        while i < len(listLeftHalf) and j < len(listRightHalf):
            if listLeftHalf[i] < listRightHalf[j]:
                argShuffledList[k]=listLeftHalf[i]
                i=i+1
                intNumOfComp += 1
            else:
                argShuffledList[k]=listRightHalf[j]
                j=j+1
                intNumOfComp += 1

            k=k+1

        while i < len(listLeftHalf):
            argShuffledList[k]=listLeftHalf[i]
            i=i+1
            k=k+1
            intNumOfComp += 1

        while j < len(listRightHalf):
            argShuffledList[k]=listRightHalf[j]
            j=j+1
            k=k+1
            intNumOfComp += 1

    return argShuffledList, "Comparison Count: " + str(intNumOfComp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made recursion and because of that you have not counted comparison of left half list and right half list. Here is reformed correct code.

```
def MergeSort(argShuffledList):
    intNumOfComp = 0

    if len(argShuffledList)>1:
        intMidValue = len(argShuffledList)//2
        listLeftHalf = argShuffledList[:intMidValue]
        listRightHalf = argShuffledList[intMidValue:]

        left_part = MergeSort(listLeftHalf)
        right_part = MergeSort(listRightHalf)

        intNumOfComp += left_part[1] + right_part[1]

        i=0
        j=0
        k=0
        while i < len(listLeftHalf) and j < len(listRightHalf):
            intNumOfComp += 1
            if listLeftHalf[i] < listRightHalf[j]:
                argShuffledList[k]=listLeftHalf[i]
                i =i+1

            else:
                argShuffledList[k]=listRightHalf[j]
                j=j+1

            k=k+1

        while i < len(listLeftHalf):
            argShuffledList[k]=listLeftHalf[i]
            i=i+1
            k=k+1
            intNumOfComp += 1

        while j < len(listRightHalf):
            argShuffledList[k]=listRightHalf[j]
            j=j+1
            k=k+1
            intNumOfComp += 1

    return argShuffledList, intNumOfComp
```